# Unable to share a folder between Windows 7 and Ubuntu (running in VMWare)

Tags: windows-7, vmware, shared-folders

I have installed **vmware toolbox** in Ubuntu (guest OS). I tried to share a location from the settings of the virtual machine. But when I click Ok, the following error in thrown in the host (Win 7) OS.

> Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: Unknown error.

The location is not showing up in `/mnt/`
What could be the reason?

P.S I have `vmhgfs` process running in my Ubuntu VM.

I was following the [how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/) method from howtogeek.com

Comment: Sounds like the error is caused by windows and not by Ubuntu - why are you posting in askubuntu.com?

Comment: I see you asked same question on SuperUser :P Run "sudo dpkg-reconfigure vmware" to see if there are any errors when building drivers for vmware.

Comment: I have another problem. I have enable sharing the folder and mounted it. Still I am not seeing anything in the Ubuntu. THere is no shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 .Install vmware tools then try
>
> 2 .if the vmware tools are installed  then run the following command (i got the same error )

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers
vmware-config-tools.pl
```

---

It happens when { build-essential , linux-headers } packages are updated

You have to rerun " vmware-config-tools.pl "

[refer to this link for more information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools#Installing%20VMware%20tools%20on%20an%20Ubuntu%20guest#InstallingfromyourVMwarehost)

Comment: that's my experience